# Write Spark dataframe to Redshift:save StructField(user_agent,ArrayType(StringType,true),true)

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, amazon-redshift

I have a dataframe, the schema includes an Array[String] field:

```
 StructField("user_agent", ArrayType apply (StringType, true))

   ...
   myDataframe.printSchema
(an excerpt)
 |-- user_agent: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I am using com.databricks.spark.redshift package to write to Redshift.  I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to save StructField(user_agent,ArrayType(StringType,true),true) to JDBC
        at com.databricks.spark.redshift.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$schemaString$1.apply(RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala:253)
        at com.databricks.spark.redshift.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$schemaString$1.apply(RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala:233)
```

Is it possible to write such a datatype to Redshift using this package?

Comment: I had the same problem and ended up converting the array into a string.

Answer (score 1):

spark-redshift supports the following datatypes :

```
field.dataType match {
          case IntegerType => "INTEGER"
          case LongType => "BIGINT"
          case DoubleType => "DOUBLE PRECISION"
          case FloatType => "REAL"
          case ShortType => "INTEGER"
          case ByteType => "SMALLINT" // Redshift does not support the BYTE type.
          case BooleanType => "BOOLEAN"
          case StringType =>
            if (field.metadata.contains("maxlength")) {
              s"VARCHAR(${field.metadata.getLong("maxlength")})"
            } else {
              "TEXT"
            }
          case TimestampType => "TIMESTAMP"
          case DateType => "DATE"
          case t: DecimalType => s"DECIMAL(${t.precision},${t.scale})"
          case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Don't know how to save $field to JDBC")
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/redshift/RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala#L245)